# client.query not responding in node-postgres library in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I'm now learning about how to use [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) package in node.js and express in order to connect to postgres server from within Node.js. Here's the code that I wrote in, but `client.query` doesn't work at all here:

```
var pg = require("pg");

exports.batting = function(req, res) {
    var conString = "postgres://myUserName:myPassword@localhost:5432/baseball";
    var client = new pg.Client(conString);
    pg.connect(conString, function(err, result) {
        console.log("enter connect");
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("will execute a query");
            client.query("select * from batting;", function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
                console.log("success");
            });
        }
    });

}
```

Note that I wrote the code above to another file, not in a root `app.js` file.

However, when I run my app and access the appropriate url, it does return nothing. And while `enter connect` and `will execute a query` are displayed in my Terminal, it looks like that the execution stopped in `client.query` and not display `success` there.

So why does it not work as expected? I do neither have any prior experience nor knowledge of postgres - I usually use mysql and just installed postgres since heroku doesn't allow me to use mysql (actually I can use it through a third-party plugin, though). And I've been able to successfully return the result when I use mysql, so the cause is likely related to be my setup with postgres server.

Note that my postgres server is running, and I confirmed that my username, password, and dbname are correct (I did reset my password, actually).

I use node version v0.10.21 and node-postgres @2.11.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing API calls. The `client` you may use for querying is returned by the `pg.connect` function :

```
pg.connect(conString, function(err, client, done){
     // handle err here
     client.query("select * from batting;", function(err, result) {
          // handle err here
            console.log("success");
            done(); // don't forget this to have the client returned to the pool
     });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Now working correctly. Then does the API change past a few years? I'm still being confused to see different tutorials/blog posts I've read, including the official documentation at Github readme page, use different ways of writing the connect, client, and query code...

Comment: @user2360798 In fact you can still connect a client directly but the callback take different parameters and the best way is usually to use a pool using `pg.connect`. The two solutions are described [here](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres).